# Can Lysine supplement increase immunity against corona viruses?

Tags: supplement, coronavirus

Can high doses of Lysine as a supplement or from a natural source (e. g. drinking 1-2 letters of yogurt daily) increase immunity against corona viruses?
What about a combination of Lysine and an A-Z multivitamins that contains vitamins:D, C, E and Zinc? I know from a doctor that taking vitamins A,D,E and K supplements is not recommended without a reason but I'm asking about giving them to vulnerable individuals only during a pandemic.
Does it has any adverse effects (Lysine)?
I read somewhere that it is used to treat  HSV1 outbreak (cold sore) in Canada because it prevents the multiplication of viruses, does thisprinciple possibly apply to coronavirus too?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?